# Why official manual docker example does not work

Tags: node.js, docker, manjaro

I'm new to docker, so I have visited the https://www.docker.com/101-tutorial tutorial and executed, folowing their advice:

```
docker run -dp 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

This let me read the manual via `http:/localhost:80`.  This works all right and I'm presented with the official docker manual. I follow it. They say to prepare a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

which i did. I built the image: `docker build -t getting-started .` and tried to run it, `docker run -dp 3000:3000 getting-started`, but with no success. I checked with `docker ps` that this did not work. After some experimentation (with some "debugging" via an interactive docker launch, with `/bin/sh` as the initial command) I produced this Dockerfile, which **works**:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
RUN yarn add express
RUN yarn add sqlite3
CMD ["node", "app/src/index.js"]
```

I'm quite impressed that without much knowledge about docker, and with absolutely no knowledge about node.js and Alpine Linux, I managed to fix the problem myself. Now I would like to understand what's going on here.

My question is as in the title: why the original instructions from the official manual fail on my computer? Why do I have to install extra libraries and why my working files go to `/app/app` rather than just `/app`?

My environment:

```
> cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Nibia
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
> docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13-ce, build 4484c46d9d
```

My experiment with an interactive container:

```
>  docker run -it my_image /bin/sh
/app # ls 
Dockerfile    app           node_modules  package.json  yarn.lock
/app # ls app
package.json  spec          src           yarn.lock
```

Comment: What was the error you were getting when running from tutorial?

Comment: If I ran docker as detatched (-dp), there was nothing on port 3000 and docker ps did not list the container as running. When I ran it as interactive (-it /bin/sh) and then tried to run node index.js, I got errors about missing libraries (express, sqllite) and about wrong absolute paths like /app/src/ whereas the file was in /app/app/src .